# Is it possible to detect your speed relative to light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, observers, relative-motion

Let’s take two cases: (1) your velocity is constant and (2) you are accelerating.

(1) isn’t the answer no, like that’s a core idea of Einstein’s relativity stuff?

(2) I don’t know.

Comment: Your speed relative to light is the same as light's speed relative to you: _c_.  Don't over-think it!

Answer (score 1):

Light always travels at speed c, regardless of observer/reference frame. So your speed relative to light is always the same no matter what.

Comment: So, if I had a spaceship engine rival, I couldn’t say “hey my best ship can do 80% c, while you’re stuck at 60%”?

Comment: @CTMacUser 80% c relative to what, exactly?

Comment: 80% of the speed of light. Or that can’t be done unless we use a local planet or space station (ie a frame of reference) to measure our ships’ speeds?

Comment: Will the space station be "stationary"?  If so, to what?  This isn't even about SR, objects in space are whizzing around in all directions, and speed means _nothing_ unless you actually drive into one of them!  Then you learn the hard way what _relative_ speed is.

Comment: @CTMacUser whoops meant to ID you in my previous comment!

Comment: @m4r35n357 of course it’s stationary,  that’s why it is called a space “station”

Comment: @CTMacUser how would you propose measuring the speed of your ship, if not relative to some other object??

Comment: @JEB hilarious!